# Why would Netflix — and only Netflix — on every browser and the windows app crash my graphics driver?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, video, graphics-card, netflix

I'm running Windows 10, I've got an AMD Radeon R9 200 Series graphics card.

Whether it be on Firefox, Chrome or the Windows App, as soon as my mouse hovers over a video to watch the app crashes, and soon after my entire PC freezes (can't move the mouse and all other apps stop running).

I reset my computer to factory reset and updated the display driver, no effect.

Comment: "I reset my computer to factory reset"
do you mean you deleted everything and reinstalled win10?
do you have any plugins installed?
have you tried other video-streaming sites like amazon or just youtube? do they crash too?
since you say its your graphic card did you try a different one? or can you build your card into a different computer and try it there?
is your flash player updated? dont know if netflix even uses flash but could help. if it really is a netflix only thing you could also ask their customer support. the problem might be on their site.

Comment: There's no way it's a netflix issue if it's crashing my whole pc. I don't have any other subscriptions so I can't say for sure about amazon, but youtube works and so do the videos on sportsnet.ca

My reset, I just mean selecting "Reset my PC" I didn't try a different graphics card, I only have the one. Flash is updated.

Comment: Probably related to DRM.

Comment: Modern programs shouldn't be using Flash to play video, though it does seem like a graphics driver issue is at play here. Have you tried going *back* a version or two of the driver? Has this *ever* worked or has it always been a problem?

Comment: YouTube nor Netflix use Flash for any of their recent videos.  Their is a small subset on YouTube that still uses Flash for vidoe playback.  However, Netflix and YouTube could be using entirely different encoders, which would be executing different portions of the hardware within your GPU, although that is unlikely.   **What is more likely is the problem is connected to DRM. **

Comment: Yes it used to work, it's hard to know exactly when it stopped working, because I stopped watching Netflix on the computer for a while and when I came back it started crashing. I did switch to a double monitor display and windows had a major update since the change.